# Multiple lines in a column in oracle to a single row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

My oracle table is as follows ( Address column having multiple lines):

```
ID         Address
--------------------
1456897    No 61 
           11th Street
           Tatabad  Coimbatore - 641012
```

How to get the desired result as (with Address column as a single line) ?

```
ID         Address
-------------------------
1456897   No 61 , 11th Street, Tatabad  Coimbatore - 641012
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if your database has its newlines as `\x0a` or `\x0d` or `\x0d\x0a`. I therefore propose a the following solution that handles all three kind of new lines. It will *however* replace mutliple newlines with one `,`. This might be what  you want, or it might not.

```
select
  id,
  regexp_replace(
     address, 
    '('||chr(10)||'|'||chr(13)||')+', 
    ', ') as address,
   .... 
 from
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

remove new line character in the column - something like

```
SELECT REPLACE(Address_column, '\n', ' ') -- \n might be also \r\n or even \r
  FROM table_name
```

Comment: You can't use `\n` directly like that, but you can use `chr(10)` instead. ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9727/3)). You can also use `regexp_replace` which might be simpler if there are different combinations of `\n`, `\r\n`, `\n\r` etc.